# Registering Each Host Specific Value from Dictionary

Tags: shell, jenkins, yaml, ansible

We wanted to have a single playbook for all the deployments and the multiple hosts will be looped in. Ansible calls will be made from Jenkins pipeline by passing in the environments, for example dev6 and dev8

```
env1=dev6
env2=dev8
```

Pipeline Call:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts --limit $env1:$env2 deploy_test.yml -e "env1={{$env1}} env2={{$env2}}"
```

I defined all the host specific variables (dev1,dev2......PERF8 etc.) in single file so it is easy to manage and maintain,

```
dev6:
  - { deploy_domain: "Dev6Domain",
      WL_Admin: "DEV6WLAdmin",
      WL_Managed: "DEV6Managed" }

dev7:
  - { deploy_domain: "Dev7Domain",
      WL_Admin: "Dev7WLAdmin",
      WL_Managed: "Dev7Managed" }
```

Playbook "Deploy_test.yml"

```
- hosts: all
  vars_files:
   - host_variables.yml
  tasks:

    - debug: msg='Target Domain is "{{ item[0].deploy_domain }}"'
      with_nested:
        - "{{ env1 }}"
        - "{{ env2 }}"
```

The env1 and env2 values are being read from jenkins, no issues there

Problem-1: When the playbook runs on dev6 first, it takes dev8 values as well since it is defined under with_nested items.

Problem-2: How do I register the values specific to every environment?
           for example, down the playbook when I say, mkdir         /tmp/{{deploy_domain}, I need seperate values for dev6 and dev8.

Comment: It's hard to understand what do you try to achieve. You use `dev#` to limit hosts – is it a group with multiple hosts or just single host? You use `with_nested` to glue two single items from `dev#`, which always produce single iteration on your example. I guess you will get more help if you describe your real task.

Comment: It is a single host. Here is how the inventory looks like
[dev6]
dev6host.xyz.com
[dev8]
dev8host.xyz.com

The central idea is that "env" (dev6, dev8 here) values will be passed from the pipeline and ansible calls for deployment based on that information. The env specific values are defined as dictionary (as mentioned above) in host_variables.yml.

Comment: Based on the env values passed on from the pipeline to ansible, the ansible should be able to read the env specific dictionary and parse the values for each environment, which IT DOES but the problem is its taking 2nd environment values into consideration during 1st environment play.
So when I register some value, for example, from the above example, register: target_domain, it is taking both dev6 and dev8 values which is a problem because if I do mkdir /tmp/{{ target_domain}} it has 2 values. What I need is one value for each environment, which is not happening currently

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to define `deploy_domain`, `WL_Admin` and `WL_Managed` different values for groups `dev6` and `dev7`, but you want them to be defined in a single file. If you want it to be in a single file you have to define those variables in the inventory file which in your case is the `hosts` file. What you are doing here is you are basically defining two variables `dev6` and `dev7` which are set on all hosts which are run in the play.

Comment: Right! So is there a way we could limit running the host specific variables ONLY per play?

Comment: I wanted to keep the host specific variables separate from the inventory as dictionaries

Comment: You can place you variables into `group_vars/dev#` subfolders near your playbook.

Comment: Why do you use flow style mappings and not the much more natural block style for the single elements that are the values for the toplevel keys. That is less readable and maintanable, if you add a key-value pair after `WL_managed` and forget to append a comma on the line before, you end up with invalid YAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example how you can read name-specific variable for every host:

hosts:

```
[dev6]
box1
[dev8]
box2
```

host_variables.yml:

```
dev6:
  deploy_domain: "Dev6Domain"
  WL_Admin: "DEV6WLAdmin"
  WL_Managed: "DEV6Managed"

dev8:
  deploy_domain: "Dev8Domain"
  WL_Admin: "Dev8WLAdmin"
  WL_Managed: "Dev8Managed"
```

I stripped out list level from original host_variables.yml, because it is not necessary in this case, there is always single element in the list.

deploy_test.yml:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_vars: host_variables.yml
    - set_fact:
        my_env: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][group_names[0]] }}"
    - debug: msg="My domain = {{ my_env.deploy_domain }}"
```

execution: `ansible-playbook -i hosts --limit $env1:$env2 deploy_test.yml`

This will execute `deploy_test.yml` for all hosts in groups set in env vars `env1` and `env2`.
In the begining of playbook, we load everything from `host_variables.yml` as host facts.
And with `set_fact` extract variable named after current host's group name as `my_env`.
So `box1` will have `dev6` as `my_env` and `box2` will have `dev8`.

Comment: @Anthon thanks for comment, I've updated the answer with explanation. As to quotes, I was lazy to correct all things, just major ones.

Comment: Thanks! But, here is an error I am getting.

+ ansible-playbook -i hosts --limit dev6:dev8 deploy_test.yml

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************
TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [dev6.xyz.com]
ok: [dev8.xyz.com]
TASK [include_vars] 
ok: [dev6.xyz.com]
ok: [dev6.xyz.com]

TASK [set_fact]
fatal: [dev6.xyz.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute u'dev'"}
fatal: [dev8.xyz.com]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute u'dev'"}

Comment: Added comment:
In my hosts file, the dev6 and dev8 are under [dev:vars]

Comment: OK...So I was able to overcome this by changing,
my_env: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][group_names[1]] }}"


The output prints me the values of DEV7 instead of dev8 coz they share the same host with different domains,


[dev7]
he3ilixmid068.xyz.com
[dev8]
he3ilxdmid068.xyz.com

host_variables.yml, looks like,


dev7:
  deploy_domain: "Dev7Domain"
  WL_Admin: "Dev7WLAdmin"
  WL_Managed: "Dev7Managed"

dev8:
  deploy_domain: "Dev8Domain"
  WL_Admin: "Dev8WLAdmin"
  WL_Managed: "Dev8Managed"

Comment: Could you suggest how this can be overcome?

Comment: I'm sorry, but no. My answer has enough information to modify it to your needs.

Comment: This solution works when every hostname is different in all groups not when you have the same hostname in multiple groups or within the same group!

Comment: @Anthon Do you have a suggestion in this case when box1 and box2 (mentioned in the above example) share the same hostname but possess different variables, such as deploy_domain, WL_Managed etc..?